# TypeError: instance.render is not a function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Hello good evening devs my problem is the following react when trying to load my application gives me the following error

[Error React](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdXQb.png)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle } from 'reactstrap';


class DishDetail extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    }
  }

  renderDish(dish) {
    if(dish != null) {
      return (
        <Card>
            <CardImg top src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
            <CardBody>
            <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
            <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
            </CardBody>
        </Card>
      );
    }

    else {
      return (
        <div></div>
      );
    }   
  }

  renderComments(dish) {
    if (dish.comments != null) {
      const comments = this.props.dish.comments.map(review => (
          <div key={review.id}>          
            <ul className="list-unstyled">
              {comments}             
              <li className="list-item">{review.comment}</li>
              <li className="list-item">{review.author}</li>
              <li className="list-item">{review.date}</li>
            </ul>
          </div>       
      ));     
    }
    else {
      return (
        <div></div>
      );      
    }

    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
          {this.renderDish(this.props.selectedDish)} 
        </div>
        <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
          <h4>comments</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default DishDetail;
```

I have made several changes to the code I am using the ES6 syntax, I would appreciate your help as I am trying to render from one component to another

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in react class component you need to use `render` function to return the jsx you want to render if the last return is something you want to render then do it like this:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Card, CardImg, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle } from 'reactstrap';
    
    
    class DishDetail extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
    
        }
      }
    
      renderDish(dish) {
        if(dish != null) {
          return (
            <Card>
                <CardImg top src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                <CardBody>
                <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
                </CardBody>
            </Card>
          );
        }
    
        else {
          return (
            <div></div>
          );
        }   
      }
    
      renderComments(dish) {
        if (dish.comments != null) {
          const comments = this.props.dish.comments.map(review => (
              <div key={review.id}>          
                <ul className="list-unstyled">
                  {comments}             
                  <li className="list-item">{review.comment}</li>
                  <li className="list-item">{review.author}</li>
                  <li className="list-item">{review.date}</li>
                </ul>
              </div>       
          ));     
        }
        else {
          return (
            <div></div>
          );      
        }
    
      }
     render(){
      return (
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
              {this.renderDish(this.props.selectedDish)} 
            </div>
            <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
              <h4>comments</h4>
              <div>{this.renderComments(this.props.selectedDish)}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
    }
    
    export default DishDetail;
```

Comment: Thanks you so much bro @aravind_reddy your solution worked beautifully!!

Comment: I need to render the comments in the view but so far I haven't been able to do it. @aravind_reddy

Comment: @wildsrincon i have updated the answer you need to call the `renderComments` from render return to be able to see on the screem